# HttpGet is not working in android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I am trying make a request and get response from server. Here is my HttpGet request.

```
public static String getAddress() throws Exception {
        final HttpGet get = new HttpGet("192.168.1.4:3000/api/1.0/geo/address/lookup");
    }
```

My server side is written by ruby on rails.

routes.rb

```
map.with_options(:controller => "geo") do |geo|
    geo.geo_lookup_address "/api/1.0/geo/address/lookup", :action => "lookup_address"
```

my controller is

```
class GeoController < ApiController
def lookup_address
      puts "lookup"
  end
end
```

my html is lookup_address.html.erb

```
<h1>GEO</h1>
```

When I type the address in browser(192.168.1.4:3000/api/1.0/geo/address/lookup) I see the result GEO, but when I use that in android application it doesn't work I check and I have an exception on HttpGet request, but the problem is I can't find out what's execption exactly is.
is there any solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
"http://192.168.1.4:3000/api/1.0/geo/address/lookup"
```

As I see in your question You missed `http://` in your **URL** in `HttpGet`..

Also don't forget to add permission in your Application's Manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: oooo I forgot put http:// thanks it works bro